# jquery div carousel

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am wondering how I create a jQuery carousel where I can browse through divs rather than images. 
So I want to browse an image, with some description text. Is this possible? And how is it done?

Comment: done same way image sliders do it. There are lots and lots of content slider plugins available... try google

Answer (score 4):

Google my friend, Google.

These ones seem quite good: http://www.codegrape.com/item/div-carousel-jquery-content-slider/1420 and http://baijs.nl/tinycarousel/

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html and http://codecanyon.net/item/showbiz-business-carousel-jquery-plugin/926348 seem to suffice as well (as IAlwaysAcceptAnswer and 3dgoo suggested)...

Answer (score 0):

Better to get an existing one and modify it to your needs. Like for example this one
http://codecanyon.net/item/showbiz-business-carousel-jquery-plugin/926348

I believe there's somewhere on the internet a free version of it available as well....

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example of plugin that will do this:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html#s6